# Values Looping Due To GetDate()

Tags: c#

The values are somehow looping. I am getting 14 same values instead of one. I have checked everything in the code. If I exclude next_expected_time <= GetDate()
then it returns just 1 value which is fine.

The code simply compares the column value with the present date and inserts into the next table.

```
code:       private void pictureBox11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Res;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DIPAYN;Initial Catalog=Highway;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {



                cmd.Connection = conn;



                 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Alert(vehicle_no, last_checkpoint) SELECT vehicle_no,checkpoint_id FROM Entry WHERE next_expected_time <= GetDate()";
               // cmd.CommandText = "Insert Alert(vehicle_no) values(21)";

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    Res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Res = -1;

                }
                finally { conn.Close(); }

                Alert al = new Alert();
                al.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds to me like there are 14 `Entry` records that fit the `WHERE` clause..And in that scenario, everything is working as it should

Comment: I expect the fix to be evaluating current timestamp in the code (with DateTime.Now) then using it in sql query as a constant.

Comment: No, I am certain there are 6 distinct rows in the db table that fits the where clause. However, it is storing 6*14 values in the table.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer Mr. Cyanide?